# Почему не работает код аккордиона?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Код вообще не реагирует на клики, в чем может быть проблема?

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion_item');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.lenght; i++) {
  elements[i].onclick = function() {
    console.log(1);
    for(var j = 0; j < elements.lenght; j++) {
      if(elements[j].classList.contains('open') == true) {
        elements[j].classList.remove('open');
        elements[j].lastChild.style.height = '0';
      }
    }
    var accordionContent = this.lastChild;
    var accordionContentStyle = getComputedStyle(accordionContent);
    if (parseInt(accordionContentStyle) == 0) {
      accordionContent.style.height = scrollHeight + 'px';
      accordionContent.classList.add('open');
    } else {
      accordionContent.style.height = 0;
      accordionContent.classList.remove('open');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  backgoround-color: #ddddd;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 30px;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.accordion_item {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.accordion_name {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.accordion_name h2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  display: inline-block;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.accordion_name h2:hover svg {
  stroke: orange;
}

svg {
  stroke: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  fill: #dddddd;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

svg:hover {
  stroke: orange;
}

.accordion_content {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="accordion_item">
    <div class="accordion_name">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 -1 202 34" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path d='M200 32 L0 32, 0 0, 65 0, 110 32' stroke-width='1'/>
</svg>
      <h2>One accordiont line</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_content">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente molestias inventore cum. Eligendi ad quae, veritatis nostrum dolores doloremque culpa. Nam sequi omnis fugiat sed. Enim ipsum rerum iure quisquam.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_item">
    <div class="accordion_name">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 -1 202 34" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path d='M200 32 L0 32, 0 0, 65 0, 110 32' stroke-width='1'/>
</svg>
      <h2>One accordiont line</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_content">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente molestias inventore cum. Eligendi ad quae, veritatis nostrum dolores doloremque culpa. Nam sequi omnis fugiat sed. Enim ipsum rerum iure quisquam.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_item">
    <div class="accordion_name">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 -1 202 34" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path d='M200 32 L0 32, 0 0, 65 0, 110 32' stroke-width='1'/>
</svg>
      <h2>One accordiont line</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_content">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente molestias inventore cum. Eligendi ad quae, veritatis nostrum dolores doloremque culpa. Nam sequi omnis fugiat sed. Enim ipsum rerum iure quisquam.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Не lenght , а **length**.

Не this.lastChild , а **this.lastElementChild**

А дальше scrollHeight нужно как минимуму взять у какого-то элемента, но контент который вы открываете он уже равен нулю.

Если не нужна плавная анимация открытия, то достаточно значения **'auto'**, если нужна, тогда думайте, как вместо 'auto' подставить нужную высоту

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion_item');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].onclick = function() {
    for(var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
      if(elements[j].classList.contains('open') == true) {
        elements[j].classList.remove('open');
        elements[j].lastChild.style.height = '0';
      }
    }
    var accordionContent = this.lastElementChild;
    var accordionContentStyle = getComputedStyle(accordionContent);
    if (parseInt(accordionContentStyle.getPropertyValue("height")) == 0) {
      accordionContent.style.height = 'auto';
      accordionContent.classList.add('open');
    } else {
      accordionContent.style.height = 0;
      accordionContent.classList.remove('open');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  backgoround-color: #ddddd;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 30px;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.accordion_item {
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.accordion_name {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.accordion_name h2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  display: inline-block;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.accordion_name h2:hover svg {
  stroke: orange;
}

svg {
  stroke: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  fill: #dddddd;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

svg:hover {
  stroke: orange;
}

.accordion_content {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="accordion_item">
    <div class="accordion_name">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 -1 202 34" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path d='M200 32 L0 32, 0 0, 65 0, 110 32' stroke-width='1'/>
</svg>
      <h2>One accordiont line</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_content">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente molestias inventore cum. Eligendi ad quae, veritatis nostrum dolores doloremque culpa. Nam sequi omnis fugiat sed. Enim ipsum rerum iure quisquam.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_item">
    <div class="accordion_name">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 -1 202 34" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path d='M200 32 L0 32, 0 0, 65 0, 110 32' stroke-width='1'/>
</svg>
      <h2>One accordiont line</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_content">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente molestias inventore cum. Eligendi ad quae, veritatis nostrum dolores doloremque culpa. Nam sequi omnis fugiat sed. Enim ipsum rerum iure quisquam.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_item">
    <div class="accordion_name">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 -1 202 34" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path d='M200 32 L0 32, 0 0, 65 0, 110 32' stroke-width='1'/>
</svg>
      <h2>One accordiont line</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_content">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente molestias inventore cum. Eligendi ad quae, veritatis nostrum dolores doloremque culpa. Nam sequi omnis fugiat sed. Enim ipsum rerum iure quisquam.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```